# How to find a binary tree depth using breadth-first algorithm in Golang

Tags: go, binary-tree, traversal

I have a binary tree and I would like to find its maximum depth using a breadth-first approach.

I think I am having a logical error in where to increment the depth.

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import (
    "log"
    "math"
)

type Queue []*Node

func (q *Queue) Enqueue(n *Node) {
    *q = append(*q, n)
}

func (q *Queue) Dequeue() *Node {
    node := (*q)[0]
    *q = (*q)[1:]
    return node
}

func (q *Queue) IsEmpty() bool {
    return len(*q) == 0
}

type Node struct {
    value *int
    left  *Node
    right *Node
}

func (node *Node) insert(value int) {
    if node.value == nil {
        node.value = &value
        return
    }

    if *node.value <= value {
        if node.left == nil {
            node.left = &Node{}
        }
        node.left.insert(value)
        return
    }

    if node.right == nil {
        node.right = &Node{}
    }
    node.right.insert(value)
}

// HELP NEEDED here
func (node *Node) NumberOfVisibleNodes() int {
    var counter int
    if node == nil || node.value == nil {
        return counter
    }

    hashtable := map[int]int{}
    levelDepth := 0
    nodeQueue := Queue{node}
    for !nodeQueue.IsEmpty() {
        currentNode := nodeQueue.Dequeue()

        _, found := hashtable[levelDepth]
        if !found {
            hashtable[levelDepth] = *currentNode.value
        }

        if currentNode.left != nil {
            nodeQueue.Enqueue(currentNode.left)
            hashtable[levelDepth+1] = *currentNode.left.value
        }

        if currentNode.right != nil {
            nodeQueue.Enqueue(currentNode.right)
            hashtable[levelDepth+1] = *currentNode.right.value
        }

        levelDepth++
    }
    return len(hashtable)
}

func (node *Node) NumberOfVisibleNodesRecursively() int {
    if node == nil || node.value == nil {
        return 0
    }
    leftMaxDepth := node.left.NumberOfVisibleNodesRecursively()
    rightMaxDepth := node.right.NumberOfVisibleNodesRecursively()
    maxDepth := math.Max(float64(leftMaxDepth), float64(rightMaxDepth))
    return 1 + int(maxDepth)
}

func main() {
    testCases := []struct {
        expect    string
        arguments []int
        expected  int
    }{
        {
            "expect to return 0 when nodes are empty",
            []int{},
            0,
        },
        {
            "expect to get 2",
            []int{3, 5},
            2,
        },
        {
            "expect to get 3",
            []int{3, 5, 2, 6, 4, 1},
            3,
        },
        {
            "expect to return 4",
            []int{3, 5, 2, 6, 4, 1, -10},
            4,
        },
    }

    for _, testCase := range testCases {
        var tree Node

        for _, value := range testCase.arguments {
            tree.insert(value)
        }

        gotResult := tree.NumberOfVisibleNodes()

        if gotResult != testCase.expected {
            log.Fatalf("%s but got: %d wanted: %d ", testCase.expect, gotResult, testCase.expected)
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if it's even possible. I know the best approach is to use a depth-first approach but I am curious to learn if the breadth approach is possible!

Running code is here: https://go.dev/play/p/exiI-QqRWIM

[UPDATE]
One approach that seems to work is using a tuple.

```
type TupleQueue []Tuple

func (tq *TupleQueue) Enqueue(t Tuple) {
    *tq = append(*tq, t)
}

func (tq *TupleQueue) Dequeue() Tuple {
    tuple := (*tq)[0]
    *tq = (*tq)[1:]
    return tuple
}

func (tq *TupleQueue) IsEmpty() bool {
    return len(*tq) == 0
}

func (node *Node) NumberOfVisibleNodes() int {
    if node == nil || node.value == nil {
        return 0
    }
    var depth int
    tupleQueue := TupleQueue{{depth, node}}
    for !tupleQueue.IsEmpty() {
        tuple := tupleQueue.Dequeue()
        if tuple.level != depth {
            depth++
        }

        if tuple.node.left != nil {
            tupleQueue.Enqueue(Tuple{depth + 1, tuple.node.left})
        }

        if tuple.node.right != nil {
            tupleQueue.Enqueue(Tuple{depth + 1, tuple.node.right})
        }
    }

    return depth + 1
}
```

I wonder if we can do something similar with hashmaps

Answer (score 0):

You don't need tuple or hashmap to do BFS. Just use queue, I show the code below.

```golang
func (node *Node) NumberOfVisibleNodes() int {
    if node == nil || node.value == nil {
        return 0
    }

    levelDepth := 0
    nodeQueue := Queue{node}
    for !nodeQueue.IsEmpty() {
        tmpQueue := Queue{}
        for !nodeQueue.IsEmpty(){
            cNode := nodeQueue.Dequeue()
            if cNode.right!= nil{
                tmpQueue.Enqueue(cNode.right)
            }

            if cNode.left!= nil{
                tmpQueue.Enqueue(cNode.left)
            }
        }

        nodeQueue = tmpQueue
        levelDepth++
    }
    return levelDepth
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking about **breadth**-first search